# Raphael transform object diagonally and infinite setIntervals

Tags: javascript, loops, animation, raphael, transform

I'm working on a small animation where the user drags a circle and the circle returns back to the starting point. I figured out a way to have the circle return to the starting point. The only problem is that it will hit one of the sides of the frame before returning. Is it possible for it to go straight back (follow the path of a line drawn between the shape and starting point).

The other problem is that my setInterval doesn't want to stop. If you try pulling it a second time it would pull it back before you release your mouse. It also seems to speed up after every time. I have tried using a while loop with a timer but the results weren't as good. Is this fixable?

```
    var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 320, 200);
    //var path = paper.path("M10 10L40 40").attr({stoke:'#000000'});
    //var pathArray = path.attr("path");
    var circle = paper.circle(50, 50, 20);
    var newX;
    var newY;
    circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
    circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");



     var start = function () {
        this.attr({cx: 50, cy: 50});
        this.cx = this.attr("cx"),
        this.cy = this.attr("cy");
     },
     move = function (dx, dy) {
        var X = this.cx + dx,
        Y = this.cy + dy;
        this.attr({cx: X, cy: Y});
     },

     up = function () {
        setInterval(function () {
    if(circle.attr('cx') > 50){
        circle.attr({cx : (circle.attr('cx') - 1)});
    } else if (circle.attr('cx') < 50){
        circle.attr({cx : (circle.attr('cx') + 1)});
    } 

    if(circle.attr('cy') > 50){
        circle.attr({cy : (circle.attr('cy') - 1)});
    } else if (circle.attr('cy') < 50){
        circle.attr({cy : (circle.attr('cy') + 1)});
    } 
   path.attr({path: pathArray});
},2);
 };
```

circle.drag(move, start, up);

Here's the Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uznp2/

Thanks alot :D

Comment: Using setInterval to animate something is an awful method. In Raphael, we can utilise the Element.animate() method, with a lot of additional advantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the "up" function to the one below

```
up = function () {
  //starting x, y of circle to go back to
  var interval = 1000;
  var startingPointX = 50;
  var startingPointY = 50;
  var centerX = this.getBBox().x + (this.attr("r")/2);
  var centerY = this.getBBox().y + (this.attr("r")/2);
  var transX = (centerX - startingPointX) * -1;
  var transY = (centerY - startingPointY) * -1;
  this.animate({transform: "...T"+transX+", "+transY}, interval);
};
```

and the "start" function as follows:

```
var start = function () {
  this.cx = this.attr("cx"),
  this.cy = this.attr("cy");
}
```

Is this the behavior you are looking for? Sorry if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Animating the transform property is right, better and faster than animating cx and cy properties. And this also has to be taken into account in the drag start and move handlers to be consistent. This way, `getBBox` will havr to be called with a `true` argument.

Comment: Hi, one quick question. The reason why I choose the setInterval method was because I needed a path to follow along with it. I got most of the path working except when the circle comes back. Do you think their is a way to find this? http://jsfiddle.net/roflcopterofl/Uznp2/

Answer (score 0):

If the circle need to get back to its initial position post drag, we can achieve that via simple animation using transform attribute.

```
// Assuming that (50,50) is the location the circle prior to drag-move (as seen in the code provided)
// The animation is set to execute in 1000 milliseconds, using the easing function of 'easeIn'.
up = function () {
   circle.animate({transform: 'T50,50'}, 1000, 'easeIn');
};
```

Hope this helps.